# recursion in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, recursion

I am implementing a switch/case expression through dictionary in Python. Can anyone tell me why the following recursive call is wrong?

I am getting an exception: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

```
def rec(x):
    return {
        'a': 'one',
        'b': 'two',
        'ac': rec('a'),
    }.get(x,x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting infinite recursion is because you're telling Python to store the *result* of the recursive call `rec('a')` in the dictionary. This means it recurses unconditionally, since you always build the dictionary before doing the lookup.

One way to solve this would be to store `lambda` functions in the dictionary, and then only call the one you `get`. In this version, the recursive call is only made when the appropriate `x` value is passed in:

```
def rec(x):
    return {
        'a': lambda: 'one',
        'b': lambda: 'two',
        'ac': lambda: rec('a'),
    }.get(x, lambda: x)()
```

Unfortunately, that's a bit cumbersome. I'm not sure I'd bother if there were just have three cases and a default. I'd just use a series of `if` statements, even though that might not be as efficient as a dictionary lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Your dict values are not put in lazily, which means it *always* creates the dict

```
{
    'a': 'one',
    'b': 'two',
    'ac': rec('a'),
}
```

whether you look up `'ac'` or not. As such, you can't just look up `'a'` in your recursive call -- you have to make the dict (recursing another layer) first.

You'll have to write this code another way.